# In C++/CLI, how to get the selected text from a ListBox?

Tags: listbox, c++-cli

In my Visual Studio C++/CLI program, `ListBox lsbGender` contains two values ("Female" and "Male"), and "Male" (at index 1) is selected.

I tried `lsbGender->GetItemText(lsbGender->SelectedIndex)`, but it returns "1" instead of "Male".

How to get the selected text ("Male") instead of "1"?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) `GetItemText` (inherited from `ListControl`) does not expect an index of an object as a parameter, but rather the object itself (which is supposed to be one of the items in the list).

Instead you can use one of the following 2 options to get the selected item text (assuming **single selection** in the `ListBox`):

1. The shortest way using [`SelectedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property:

```
System::String ^ txt = lsbGender->SelectedItem->ToString();
```

2. A more general way of accessing a `ListBox` item using the [`Items`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.items?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) (and [`SelectedIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex?view=windowsdesktop-6.0))  properties:

```
System::String ^ txt = lsbGender->Items[lsbGender->SelectedIndex]->ToString();
```